# How to create a classified section in place of comments_template

Tags: comment-form, comments-template

I am running a site where users can find great information about musical artists and their releases. Each release is a wordpress post. Each artist is a wordpress post. In my `single-artist.php` and my `single-release.php`, i use

```php
comments_template();
```

EDIT: here is my comments.php

```
comment_form();

if (have_comments()) : 

    $wantto= get_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'wantto', true );
    echo '<ol class="post-comments">';
            wp_list_comments(array(
                'style'       => 'ol',
                'short_ping'  => true,
            ));
            echo $wantto;
          
    echo '</ol>';
endif;
```

It just shows a text box. Here's an example of a page with a comment form.

https://staging3.recordcollectorsoftheworldunite.com/artist/021-2/

What I'd like to do is create a new field, a dropdown menu, that tags their post. It will have 3 options:

- "WANT TO BUY"
- "WANT TO SELL"
- "INFO".

I'd also like to add some fields, depending on which option they choose- if "WANT TO BUY", or "WANT TO SELL", I'd like to add a price field. If "WANT TO SELL", I'd like to add a "condition of the item" field.

I'd like the value they choose to be able to be queried as well, so I can make a page that queries "Latest items for sale", etc.

This way users can interact with each other around the site. If you want to buy Madonna ticket stubs, dropdown the menu to "WANT TO BUY" and tell us what you're looking for. In the same way, you can do that for selling items, and sharing info about the page.

I'm not married to `comments_template()`, it's just what I'm using now. Is it best to modify the template for comment form, or use another avenue to make this work?

I'd prefer to do all this without a store/market plugin. They seem overcomplicated for what i'm looking for. However, if that's the best way to go, let me know and I'll look into that.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a three step process.

1. You can use `comment_form_logged_in_after` (for logged in users) and/or `comment_form_after_fields` (for non-logged in users) actions to add your custom fields.
2. Save the values as comment meta using `update_comment_meta` function hooked into `comment_post` action.
3. Get the values using `get_comment_meta`.

**EDIT:** 25-05-2022

Try this..

```
/*
 * This will add the fields to the comment form
*/
function wpse406058_custom_comment_fields() {

    echo '<p class="comment-form-wantto">';
    echo '<label for="wantto">I Want To</label>';
    echo '<select id="wantto" name="wantto" class="myclass">';
        echo '<option value="WANT TO BUY">WANT TO BUY</option>';
        echo '<option value="WANT TO SELL">WANT TO SELL</option>';
        echo '<option value="INFO">INFO</option>';
    echo '</select>';

}
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'wpse406058_custom_comment_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'wpse406058_custom_comment_fields' );

/*
 * This will field value as comment meta
*/
function wpse406058_save_custom_field($comment_id) {

    if ( isset($_POST['wantto']) && !empty($_POST['wantto']) ) {
        $wantto = sanitize_text_field($_POST['wantto']);
        update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'wantto', $wantto );
    }
    
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wpse406058_save_custom_field' );
```

Now you can get the value using `get_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'wantto', true );`

One option to display the value would be filtering the comment text.

```
function wpse406058_display_comment_meta( $comment_text ) {
    
    $wantto = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'wantto', true );
    
    if ( isset($wantto) && !empty($wantto) ) {
    
        $wanttotext = '<p class="wantosec">' . esc_html($wantto) . '</p>';
        
        $comment_text = $wanttotext . $comment_text;
    }
    
    return $comment_text;

}
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpse406058_display_comment_meta' );
```

Comment: This is great! Forgive my ignorance- Should I include this code in my single-artist.php or in my functions, or in my comments.php?

Comment: After some research, I think I need to create a function, and add these into it. How do I write these actions into a function? Thank you

Comment: @RCOTWUnite Edited my answer and added the code. You might want to conditionally check for the post type of the comment to display that field in your post type only.

Comment: If I could upvote again, I would. I know I'm not supposed to ask side questions, but this one's important. I've not seen sanitize_text_field yet, seems like I should use that on ALL of my $_POST where users give input. This protects me from injection attacks? Thanks

Comment: OK and I'm going to try putting this in the comments.php and see what happens. Let me know if this should go in functions instead. Thanks!

Comment: I added this into my comments.php, it added the options. YAY! Thanks!

Comment: @RCOTWUnite These code goes into your theme's `functions.php` file. And, for your second question about data sanitation, you can read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) and [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data). In any case, user inputted data should always be sanitized before saving to database.

Comment: Thank you, that is so helpful. I'll read up on those. I switched them to the functions.php . Still seeing the options. Great! However, I can't seem to get the value to display. I've tried `echo $wantto` and `echo $commentid` and neither display anything. I've tried `$commentid =get_comment_ID()` , then `echo $commentid` and still nothing displayed. I don't quite get it yet. How can I display the results as part of the comment?

Comment: I added my comments.php to show what the `comments_template()` is fetching.

Comment: @RCOTWUnite check my edited answer. The whole piece of code goes to theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Thank you! I put it in `functions` and the page crashed. When I take it back out, the page loads. if i delete everything inside the function and write `echo 'hi';`, it still crashes. Any idea as to what could be happening? Thanks again.

Comment: @RCOTWUnite Sory, my bad. there was a typo in the function name. fixed it and it should work now.

Comment: Thanks so much! That works. Thanks again Abhik!

Comment: I made a new question for this, but maybe there's a quick answer in here. How would I only display comments with certain tags? Would I make a new function that has an `if $wantto="BUY"` then return the result in there?